# How does a JDBC driver implementation work?

Tags: jdbc, driver

A JDBC driver implementation provides the low level details that allows a client to communicate with a third party datababase. I am just curious what it is doing behind the scenes. Communication between two systems written in different languages usually happens through web services.

Does the jdbc driver use web services to communicate between the client and the db server? Or am i oversimplifying?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver

Comment: JDBC drivers use the low-level protocol of the database, and those protocols are usually not implemented using webservices, but with sockets.

Comment: I think you should first read what JDBC driver's are and what are different requirements for accessing database in Java using JDBC.

Comment: "Communication between two systems written in different languages usually happens through web services." No it doesn't. It's been going on a lot longer than Web Services have been around. Consider FTP, Telnet, SSH, HTTP itself for a start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

People who write JDBC drivers have [several options](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) to choose from:

- Type 1 driver: Use the generic JDBC-ODBC bridge, don't actually make a driver.
- Type 2: Make a "wrapper" that uses JNI to call functions in a native client library.
- Type 3: A generic driver that connects to a "middleware" service that talks with the database.
- Type 4: a pure-Java implementation of the database communication protocol.

A type 3 driver might use web services to talk with the middleware. The other types of driver most likely communicate in a database-specific binary protocol over TCP/IP sockets (if the database is on a remote host) or other suitable reliable transport, not through web services.

Comment: Which part of it is unsure, @Ajay?

Comment: +1 for this excellent answer. @AjayBhojak Your comments are incomprensible, and I certainly don't know what on earth you mean by 'information should not be shared'. That's the purpose of this site.

Comment: Maybe you people use SOAP and WSDL in your driver implementation. You should check driver APIs. This is what I meant because you would never find a web service client implementation in driver Apis.

Comment: EJP I wrote "UNsure information should not be shared"  and this means that you should answer when you know what to answer.

Answer (score 0):

**You should check this [link](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/tutorials/j-jdbc/section3.html) as this shows you how JDBC works.**

Now coming to your question : No JDBC do not use web services. The way it connects to different types of databases is due to the database vendors because different database vendors provide their own driver implementation and you just need to use that implementation. There's nothing like web services. Each database vendor provides you with some api of their own to access database which they map to the Java's api to access database which is generic. 
Java is provides a generic api for database operations which ultimately does operations and communication with database using sockets.

So what you need to read is TCP/IP , Socket programming, IO and JDBC. Please don't forget to check the link it will surely help you understand the concept.